# Typescript - generic transformer type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0, typescript-generics

I am having a bit of trouble with generics and was hoping for some guidance.
There is a working example [available here](https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-monad-890le?file=/src/App.tsx). This example is contrived to keep the example simple.

I would've thought that the `T` in the `Transformer` type would be inferred without issue but that is not the case.
The reason `Transformer` returns `T | K` is that the transformer defaults to an `identity` function

```js
const multiply = (a: number) => (b: number) => a * b;
const identity = <T extends any>(a: T) => a;
const toInt = (a: string) => parseInt(a, 10);
const by10 = multiply(10);

type Transformer = <T, K>(value: T) => T | K;

const renderContent = (
  value: string | number,
  transformer: Transformer = identity
) => {
  const transformed = transformer(value);
  console.log(transformed);
  return transformed;
};

renderContent(50, by10); // Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'number'
renderContent("50", toInt); // Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

Comment: First mistake: your `Transformer` type is not generic. It must be declared as `type Transformer<T, K>`. Second - your `renderContent` is not generic either, it should probably have a `<T extends (string|number)>` generic parameter. Third: what is `K` type? Fourth: `const identity = <T>(a: T) => a;`

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAxA8hpBvAsAKCUKXgHtgoAXJMAVwBsKBLGOgTyQF4kAKEALiTAaYAEYQATgEpOAPh4iBQ0ROkc5IJACokIgNz4ixMpSSMAJhGBMK7LgB4AKkggAPCpbNQkIYKxm8BB1V1fQIiUnIqChIASStOHn4kSnFGYABzYKQ4cSgIOIpeABokAEYABklQwwiTEVYKhNoGZjZuCqr8AyIbGGQHcR8oADMScUhxRxKAVTkubgA3EDoaCECspwAfJGnQ7sJaqnEPCQBhMnd4+ydXS89kilSMpG2lMXEZ-33DJCWVtaQDiK30MjyGo3GEkCg3IEImUx2c1MFisjBs3yyuDCPyMkSQYNhY0gZgSBJGRIki2Wq062J+tRIdAgADo6CR0twyXCIGZaTjCMcKDRxMB8TDyZCzNUiABfaUCk7ic5WSyFACs5RK9Q6uiQ32OwAsSouqu4ACINWaStEClU9XgZUA)?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the fantastic answers from @zerkms and @jcalz here is the final answer:

```js
const updateDatabase = <K>(value: K) => console.log(value);
const multiply = (a: number) => (b: number) => a * b;
const by10 = multiply(10);
const identity = <A>(a: A) => a;
const toInt = (numStr: string) => parseInt(numStr, 10);
const toStr = (num: number) => String(num);

type TransformerFn<V, T> = (value: V) => V | T;
type Option = { id: string; label: string };
type ValidInput = string | number | Option;

const renderValue = <V extends ValidInput, T extends ValidInput>(
  value: V,
  transformer: TransformerFn<V, T> = identity
) => {
  const transformed = transformer(value);
  updateDatabase(transformed);
  return transformed;
};

renderValue(10); // => 10
renderValue("10", toInt); // => 10
renderValue(10, toStr); // => '10'
renderValue(10, by10); // => 100
renderValue({ id: "blue", label: "Blue" }); // => {id: blue, label: 'Blue'}
```